# How to show a "closed" Desktop window in Ext.Net?

Tags: window, desktop, ext.net

SITUATION:

I'm developing an Ext.Net Web App using the Desktop component and I'm having trouble to open a Window after it has been created for the first time.

The cycle starts with the "Index" view, which simply builds the main Desktop environment. In this view, a Module is created which has a JS handler function as follows:

```
.Modules(
     X.DesktopModule()
         .ModuleID("ModuleTitle")
         .Shortcut(
         X.DesktopShortcut()
             .Name("Module Title")
             .IconCls("custom-icon")
              .Handler("loadModuleWindow(Desktop,'AssetManager');")
  )
```

The handler function "loadModuleWindow" then has the responsibility to decide if the Window has to be created for the first time or it has been created already and just needs to be shown again:

```
function loadModuleWindow(callingContainer, moduleId) {

    //Dynamically build name of script by convention       
    loadScriptFile("Scripts/" + moduleId + "Scripts.js", "js");

    //Only create new window if it hasn't been created already
    if (App[moduleId] == undefined) {
        App.direct.CreateModuleWindow(callingContainer.id, moduleId);
    } else {
        App[moduleId].show();
    }
}
```

When the Desktop is created and the Module called for the first time, the code-behind method "CreateModuleWindow" is called and the Window is returned to the client.

The window is setup with:

```
window.CloseAction = CloseAction.Hide;
```

All works fine up to this point, the issue comes about when the Window is closed (by clicking on it's [X] close button).
As expected, the window is hidden from the current view and the "indicator" on the task bar is removed too.

As you might have guessed, the intention of using a Handler ("loadModuleWindow") is to avoid the server call if the Window was loaded once already.

However, when the method Show() is called on this window, two things happen:

1) If I call the Show() method with no arguments, nothing happens. The Window stays hidden and it is not shown again on the desktop.

2) If I call the method like Show(callerContainer.id) to give it a target, the Window is shown on the desktop but the window "indicator" in the task bar is not reloaded and I get an error saying that the "offsetWidth" property is undefined.

QUESTION:

Does anyone know of any other method that can be called when a window has been configured with CloseAction = Hide to "restore" it to the Desktop as when created for the first time?

** *UPDATE: FULL CODE TO REPRODUCE ISSUE* **********

ENTRY POINT CONTROLLER (DektopController.cs)

```
[DirectController]
public class DesktopController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [DirectMethod(ShowMask = true)]
    public ActionResult CreateModuleWindow(string callingContainerId, string moduleId)
    {
        //Only AJAX requests are allowed
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() == true)
        {
            ControllerHelpers.CreateAndAttachWindow(this, callingContainerId, moduleId);
            return this.Direct();
        }
        else //No direct URL access
        { return new EmptyResult(); }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER HELPERS

```
    public static Window GetWindowViewModel(string moduleId)
    {
        // Dynamically instantiate the ViewModel class
        // By convention, the ViewModel that creates the Window is named
        // moduleName + "ViewModel".
        // The ViewModel should also assign the moduleId to the window.ID

        Type type = Type.GetType("App.Web.ViewModels." + moduleId + "ViewModel");

        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        return (Window)obj;
    }

    public static void CreateAndAttachWindow(Controller cont, string callingContainerId, string moduleId)
    {
        Desktop callingContainer = cont.GetCmp<Desktop>(callingContainerId);

        Window moduleWindow = GetWindowViewModel(moduleId);

        if (moduleWindow != null)
        {
            callingContainer.CreateWindow(moduleWindow);
        }
    }
```

RAZOR INDEX FILE

```
@model Ext.Net.Desktop

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Desktop";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Desktop.cshtml";
   var X = Html.X();
}

@(
 X.Desktop()
    .ID("MyDesktop")
        .Listeners(l =>
        {
            l.Ready.BroadcastOnBus = "App.Desktop1.Ready";
        })
        .Modules(
            X.DesktopModule()
                .ModuleID("Module1")
                .Shortcut(
                    X.DesktopShortcut()
                        .Name("Module 1")
                        .Handler("loadModuleWindow(App.MyDesktop,'Module1');")
                )
        )
        )
```

"loadModuleWindow" JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
function loadModuleWindow(callingContainer, moduleId) {

    //Only create new window if it hasn't been created already
    if (App[moduleId] == undefined) {
        App.direct.CreateModuleWindow(callingContainer.id, moduleId);

        //Set the returned window to the module, by convention, the
        //window.id is the same as the moduleId.
        App[callingContainer.id].getModule(moduleId).setWindow(moduleId);
    } else {
        App[callingContainer.id].getModule(moduleId).run();
    }
}
```

MODULE1 VIEW MODEL FILE

```
public class Module1ViewModel : Window
{
    public Toolbar TopToolBar {get; private set;}
    public TreePanel AssetHierarchy { get; private set; }

    public Module1ViewModel()
    {
        this.ID = "Module1";
        this.Title = "Module1";
        this.Width = 1400;
        this.Height = 600;
        this.Layout = LayoutType.Border.ToString();
        this.CloseAction = CloseAction.Hide;
        this.Stateful = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few issues.

First, the ids of Module and its Window must be unique they are separate components.

So, please change, for example, in Module1ViewModel.

```
this.ID = "Module1_Window"
```

Second, a Desktop's CreateWindow shows a Window independently from any modules and a setWindow call is not enough to attach a Window to a Module. We should have convenient methods to attach a Window to a Module, but, currently, we don't have such ones. At the moment, I can suggest the following solution.

Replace the loadModuleWindow function with:

```
function loadModuleWindow(callingContainer, moduleId) {
    var module = App[callingContainer.id].getModule(moduleId);

    if (!module.win) {
        App.direct.CreateModuleWindow(moduleId, {
            success: function (result) {
                module.autoRun = true;
                module.addWindow(function () { return eval(result)[0] });
            }
        });
    } else {
        module.run();
    }
}
```

Replace the CreateModuleWindow method with:

```
[DirectMethod(ShowMask = true)]
public ActionResult CreateModuleWindow(string moduleId)
{
    Window moduleWindow = GetWindowViewModel(moduleId);
    moduleWindow.AutoRender = false;
    string moduleWindowCfg = ComponentLoader.ToConfig(moduleWindow);

    return this.Direct(moduleWindowCfg);
}
```

Leave the rest things without any changes.

**Some notes regarding the design.**

Generally, a Desktop's Module doesn't support attaching a Window to it on the fly, because a Module is supposed to be used as an indivisible unit with its Window. It means that a Module expects a Window to be pre-defined for a Module. How it is supposed to do. You can create a Window without any assigning it to any Module or you can create a whole Module on the fly.

Comment: Hi Daniil, thank you for your reply. I've actually tried that and it doesn't work. The run() method fires createWindow() and everything that follows, but at the end the window is not "reloaded" on the Desktop.
I've tried the following permutations.

`code` App.Desktop1.getModule(moduleId).run();
App.Desktop1.getModule(moduleId).createWindow();
App.Desktop1.getModule(moduleId).shortcutItemClick(); `code`

but none of them work.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean under "reloaded"? Does it not appear?

Comment: Hi Daniil. Yes. I use the word "reloaded" to differentiate from simply showing the window. As mentioned in the post, I can use the Show(target) method, using the Desktop as the target and the window is displayed. However, the related button is not loaded on the task bar is not recreated and the maximise/minimise/close Tools of the window do not work. What I mean by "reloaded" is to bring the Window back to the foreground with its full functionality, like when it's created for the first time. Cheers.

Comment: Also, just for the sake of clarity, I should've mention in my response that the run() method of the module doesn't even show the window (like the show() method of the window itself as described above.

Comment: Clear. I cannot reproduce it. Please provide a full test case.

Comment: HI Daniil. I've just updated the post with the full test case. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Btw, what about to create a whole Module on the fly, not just a Window? Or, otherwise, do you really need that Window to be belong to any Module?

Comment: Hi Daniil. Thank you very much for the response. In fact, I'm in the middle of refactoring a little bit the code so I create the Module (and related Window) on the fly. As a matter of fact, modules will be created according to user's roles and permissions.
I guess one can't ever stop finding better ways to do things.
Thank you again for your time, it's appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Just tried the changes, but it throws an error on the execution of the:
    `module.addWindow(function () { return eval(result)[0] });`
line. The error it throws is:
    `0x800a03ec - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Expected ';'`

Comment: For whatever is worth, I copied the string generated by the result variable on the debugger and inserted it in the eval() function and it doesn't throw an error but just draws a tiny blank window. The window is resizable but has no content at all. I hope this gives you a hint, it would seem that the string returned by `ComponentLoader.ToConfig(moduleWindow)` is not formed correctly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. What IE and OS versions are you testing in? I am testing with Windows 7 + IE9. What is a controller action's response?  Btw, I have updated the answer with some info from my comments. Please read (it is at the bottom of the answer).

Comment: Hi Daniil. I'm using Win7 + IE9 too. I've followed your recommendation and I'm changing the code at the moment. The module is no longer defined on the Desktop razor file, but rather the desktop has a DirectEvent that is triggered when the Desktop is ready and loads the modules (and associated Windows) as per the user permissions.
Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Nice. Are you facing any problems with the new design? If so, I could help.

Comment: Hi Daniil. The new design is working as expected. I just found a bug that throws an error is you define a Desktop without any modules. When you try to then load the first module, the dynamically generated JS throws an error. I've raised a bug report with all the details in your website. 
At the moment I've gone around the issue by defining a "dummy" module to initialize the desktop's module collection.

Comment: Thank you for the report! I saw it and will investigate as soon as possible.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in our SVN. It will go to the upcoming v2.3.0 release.